# R code for Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process

Tags: r, mean, mean-reversion

Can any one help me with some R code to run Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process?

Comment: use rseek in Cran or look at http://pcweicfa.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/r-implementation-of-ornstein-uhlenbeck.html or http://nunn.rc.fas.harvard.edu/groups/pica/wiki/70613/512_Simulating_trait_evolution_in_R_Brownian_motion_and_OrnsteinUhlenbeck_models.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code of [Euler Maruyama simulation method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maruyama_method) is pretty simple (`nu` is long run mean, `lambda` is mean reversion speed):

```
ornstein_uhlenbeck <- function(T,n,nu,lambda,sigma,x0){
  dw  <- rnorm(n, 0, sqrt(T/n))
  dt  <- T/n
  x <- c(x0)
  for (i in 2:(n+1)) {
    x[i]  <-  x[i-1] + lambda*(nu-x[i-1])*dt + sigma*dw[i-1]
  }
  return(x);
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you provide an example of the parameters' values? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12):

Take a look at the [sde](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sde) package; specifically the `dcOU` and `dsOU` functions.  You may also find some examples on the R-SIG-Finance mailing list, which would be in the results of a search on [www.rseek.org](http://www.rseek.org).

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the [Sim.DiffProc](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Sim.DiffProc/index.html) package.

Have a look at this document:
[Sim.DiffProc: A Package for Simulation of Diffusion Processes in R](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/62/98/41/PDF/R-SimDiffProc.pdf)

See esp. chapter 2.1.2

There is even a Graphical User Interface (GUI) available for some functions:
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Sim.DiffProcGUI/index.html

See chapter 4 in the above document for details.

Comment: Ive used the SimDiffProc library to do the same but I feel the simulations are wrong. The Euler simulation process gives better results.

Comment: @Mahesh: What makes you feel, that the simulations are wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The Euler method is simple but it gives an approximate distribution. The method implemented below gives an exact distribution of $X_{t_i}$ and exact conditional distributions $(X_{t_j} \mid X_{t_i})$.

```
rOU <- function(npaths, T, nsteps, x0, theta1, theta2, theta3){
  dt <- T/nsteps
  r <- theta1/theta2
  s <- theta3*sqrt(-expm1(-2*theta2*dt)/2/theta2)
  e <- exp(-theta2*dt)
  out <- rbind(x0, matrix(NA_real_, nsteps, npaths))
  for(i in 2:(nsteps+1)){
    out[i,] <- rnorm(npaths, r+e*(out[i-1,]-r), s)
  }
  out
}
```

Let's check the covariance $Cov(X_{t_1}, X_{t_2})$:

```
 theta1 <- 1; theta2 <- 2; theta3 <- 3
> nsteps <- 10
> sims <- rOU(npaths=500000, T=1, nsteps=nsteps, x0=0, 
+             theta1=theta1, theta2=theta2, theta3=theta3)
> # check covariance
> t1 <- 1/2; t2 <- 1
> cov(sims[1+nsteps*t1,], sims[1+nsteps*t2,]) # estimated
[1] 0.713272
> theta3^2/2/theta2 * 
+   (exp(-theta2*(t2-t1)) - exp(-theta2*(t2+t1))) #exact
[1] 0.7157078
```